# Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'html' cannot be nested within element 'div'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help how to fix the error in my code. When I compile the code told me the error Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'html' cannot be nested within element 'div'. If someone know, please help me?

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageUsers.aspx.cs" Inherits="probazaadmin.ManageUsers" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server"></form>
    <div>Users Account Management</div>
    <p></p>
    <b>- The total registered users is: <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblTotalUsers" /><br />
    - The total online users at this moment: <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblOnlineUsers" /></b>
    <p></p>
    In order to display all users whose name begins with letter click on the link letter:
    <p></p>

    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAlphabetBar"
    OnItemCommand="rptAlphabetBar_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'
    CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <p></p>
    Use the below feature to search users by partial username or e-mail:
    <p></p>

    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUserSearchTypes">
    <asp:ListItem Text="UserName" Selected="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="E-mail" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    contains
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearchText" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search"
    OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </body></html>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: The error message is saying "don't put `<html>` inside `<div>`" (where the `<div>` is part of your master page). Did you have trouble understanding what the error message is saying, or how to do it?

Comment: first don't ever place `<html>` into `<div>`, second, it seems like this is a web content form, which is not a standalone web page (http://forums.asp.net/t/1326602.aspx?Web+Form+vs+Web+Content+Form) and shouldn't have `<htm>`,`<head>`,`<body>` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shows you are:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"....
```

1. using a master page (which is where the HTML declaration is)

   ```
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   ```
2. using the content <strike>page</strike> placeholder to add and entire HTML document - which you **shouldn't** do.

   - as stated, the master page is where HTML declarations go
   - ASP.net content sections are for content only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this 
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageUsers.aspx.cs" Inherits="probazaadmin.ManageUsers" %>
    
    
    
    Users Account Management

**- The total registered users is: 

    - The total online users at this moment:**

In order to display all users whose name begins with letter click on the link letter:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAlphabetBar"
OnItemCommand="rptAlphabetBar_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<p></p>
Use the below feature to search users by partial username or e-mail:
<p></p>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUserSearchTypes">
<asp:ListItem Text="UserName" Selected="true" />
<asp:ListItem Text="E-mail" />
</asp:DropDownList>
contains
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearchText" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search"
OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```